# Автоматический translateX при resize окна

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно сделать так, чтоб при *resize* окна к изображению в блоке автоматически добавлялось `translateX`

Мой скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(window).on('resize',function(){
    var width = $('.card_img_wrapper').width();
    var image = $('.product_img');
    var x = 10
    image.css('transform','translateX(- ' + x + ' + px)');
  });   
});
```

Не могу понять, как заставить `x` автоматически увеличивать и уменьшать значение, в зависимости от ширины браузера.

Пример: https://wetransfer.com/

Comment: вместо px использовать vw единицы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Решение на чистом css

Используйте `vw` еденицы. `1 vw = 1% ширины окна браузера`  Поддержка браузерами: [84%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

```css
.test {
  transform: translateX(-5vw);

  width: 100px; height: 100px;background: red
}
```

```html
<div class=test>test div</div>
```

## Решение 2

Чтобы получить ширину окна браузера используте следующую конструкцию:

```
 var width = $(window).width();
```

```js
function resize() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  var image = $('.test');
  var x = 0.05 * width;
  image.css('transform', 'translateX( -' + x + 'px)');

}
$(window).on('resize', resize);
resize()
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=test>test div</div>
```

В вашем примере, кстати лишний `+`:

```
image.css('transform', 'translateX( - ' + x + ' + px)');
```

надо так:

```
image.css('transform', 'translateX( -' + x + 'px)');
```